# Create a class, so I can call from anywhere in my application

Tags: vb.net

I found the very helpful code for my solution, but it is designed for a Form.
The question is:
How to call it from any form?

Here is the code:

---

```
    Private ArabicInput As InputLanguage
    Private EnglishInput As InputLanguage
    PrivateSub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load 
    ' Set the default as the current Inputlanguage
    ArabicInput = InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage
    EnglishInput = InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage
    'Iterate to find the available Arabic and English Keyboards
    Dim count As Integer
    count = InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages.Count
    For i As Integer = 1 To (count - 1)
    If InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages(i).LayoutName.Contains("Arabic") = True Then
    'Found an Arabic Keyboard  
    ArabicInput = InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages(i)
    Else
    If InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages(i).LayoutName.Contains("English") = True Then
    'Found an English Keyboard 
    EnglishInput = InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages(i)
    End If
    End If
    Next  i
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_Enter(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Enter
    InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = ArabicInput
    End Sub
    Private Sub TextBox2_Enter(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.Enter
    InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = EnglishInput
    End Sub
```

---

I mean how to call it from FORM2, Form3 ,...etc.

Comment: Put the common code that you want to call in a library.  If you want to call something on a form that's not in the Controls collection, expose a property or method in your Form class.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class and compile it into a .dll file. You can then add the .dll file as a reference to your form project, web page or console app.

Comment: It's pretty simple. This link http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/NET/nets11p3.html explains a very simple class and it's function. To get the .dll, you just 'build' the solution and the .dll will be in your debug folder

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Module (`Project`, `Add Module`), and the code in that module will be accessible by the forms in your project.